# VDS (Virtual Disk Service) COM interface notifications - callback (sink) invoked only during unregister (Unadvise)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I'm want to get notifications about disk add/remove (PnP) in Windows using VDS COM interface (need to support Windows 7 so I can't use the new "Windows Storage Management API").

Here's my callback class:

```
class SimpleNotifySink: public IVdsAdviseSink {
public:
    SimpleNotifySink() : ref(1) {}
    HRESULT OnNotify(
            LONG lNumberOfNotifications,
            VDS_NOTIFICATION *pNotificationArray
          )
    {
        printf("Got %d notifications:\n", lNumberOfNotifications);
        return S_OK;
    }
    ULONG AddRef() {
        InterlockedIncrement(&ref);
        return ref;
    }
    ULONG Release() {
        ULONG ulRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&ref);
            if (0 == ref)
            {
                delete this;
            }
            return ulRefCount;
    }
    HRESULT QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObj) {
        // Always set out parameter to NULL, validating it first.
            if (!ppvObj)
                return E_INVALIDARG;
            *ppvObj = NULL;
            if ((riid == IID_IUnknown) || (riid == IID_IVdsAdviseSink)) {
                // Increment the reference count and return the pointer.
                *ppvObj = (LPVOID)this;
                AddRef();
                return S_OK;
            }
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
private:
    LONG ref;
};
```

And here's the  callback registration (snippet):

```
IVdsAdviseSink *sink = new SimpleNotifySink();
DWORD cookie = 0;

hr = pService->Advise(sink, &cookie);

if (FAILED(hr)) {
    printf("sink registration (pService->Advise) failed with %X.\n", hr);
}

printf("press any key...\n");
getchar();

if (cookie != 0) {
    hr = pService->Unadvise(cookie);
}
```

To test the code, during the "press any key...", I disable and enable a virtual disk (in a VM) - but my callback is called (I've used windbg) only when pService->Unadvise(...) is called.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you are subscribing on the wrong thread and/or you don't pump window messages on this STA thread, giving eventually no control to the API to have the notification delivered. Next chance is `Unadvise` only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar` doesn't pump messages, so no COM events can be dispatched.  Replace your printf/getchar with a message pump loop; something like this:

```
HRESULT WaitAndPumpMessagesUntilKeyDown(DWORD dwMs)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    BOOL fContinue = TRUE;
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    liDueTime.QuadPart = -100000LL * dwMs;

    // Create an unnamed waitable timer.
    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);
    if (NULL == hTimer)
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    // Set a timer to wait for 10 seconds.
    if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }
    while (fContinue)
    {
        DWORD dwWaitId = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &hTimer, dwMs, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE);
        switch (dwWaitId)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            {
                fContinue = FALSE;
            }
            break;

        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            {
                MSG Msg;
                while (::PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    ::TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                    if (Msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
                    {
                        fContinue = FALSE;
                        hr = S_OK;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ::DispatchMessage(&Msg);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            {
                hr = S_FALSE;
                fContinue = FALSE;
            }
            break;

        default:// Unexpected error
            {
                fContinue = FALSE;
                hr = E_FAIL;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```